# Unable to store particular target values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(e => {
  $(".test").click(e => {
    textvalue = displayData(e);
    console.log(textvalue); //prints the array
  });
});

function displayData(e) {
  let i = 0;
  const td = $("#tbody tr td");
  let textvalues = [];

  for (const value of td) {
    if (value.dataset.name == e.target.dataset.name) {
      textvalues[i++] = value.textContent;
    }
  }
  return textvalues;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>DummyName</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>DummyEmail</td>
        <td>DummyContact</td>
        <td>DummyDepartment</td>
        <td class="test">Click</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DummyName2</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>DummyEmail2</td>
        <td>DummyContact2</td>
        <td>DummyDepartment2</td>
        <td class="test">Click</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm using jQuery to update onscreen values in a form. Complete beginner at this.

```
$(document).ready(e =>{
  $(".btnedit").click(e =>{
    textvalues = displayData(e);
    let sname = $("input[name*='name_type");
    let sage = $("input[name*='age_type");
    let sgender = $("input[name*='gender_type");
    let semail = $("input[name*='email_type");
    let scontact = $("input[name*='contact_type");
    let sdept = $("input[name*='dept_type");

    sname.val(textvalues[0]);
    sage.val(textvalues[1]);
    sgender.val(textvalues[2]);
    semail.val(textvalues[3]);
    scontact.val(textvalues[4]);
    sdept.val(textvalues[5]);


});
});

function displayData(e){
    let i = 0;
    const td = $("#tbody tr td");
    let textvalues = [];

    for(const value of td){
        if(value.dataset.name == e.target.dataset.name)
        {
            //console.log(value);
            textvalues[i++] = value.textContent;
        }
    }
    return textvalues;
}
```

I need to get the data stored in a table onto the inputs of the form, in order for the user to update it further. The user clicks on a record to edit it(which is displayed on the page).

The record values are stored in the array **textvalues**. Problem is the entire table values get stored in the array instead of just the single record.

In **value.dataset.name**, *name* is a column from the table which I'm using as the primary key (I know it's wrong, but just going with it for now).

**Edit:** Original table code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td data-name = "<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                                    <td data-name = "<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
                                    <td data-name = "<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
                                    <td data-name = "<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                                    <td data-name = "<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['contact'];?></td>
                                    <td data-name = "<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['department'];?></td>
                                    <td data-name = "<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-edit btnedit"></i></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php
                            }
```

Comment: The idiomatic way to add elements to an array is `textvalues.push(value.textContent)`

Comment: Can you add the HTML and create a [mcve]? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do for how to create an executable snippet.

Comment: @Barmar I tried to, but I'm using a lot of php so I don't think I'll be able to (or I lack the knowledge) 
I'll add in some of the HTML code as well.

Comment: @Barmar I'm referring to a repo, [link]https://github.com/akashyap2013/PHP_CRUD_Operation/blob/master/php/operation.php

Comment: You can get the HTML from `View Source` on the web page.

Comment: @Barmar I just added the minimal example, sorry for the mess

Comment: You can't use `id="test"` in every row, IDs have to be unique. Change it to `class="test"` and use `$(".test").click(...)`

Comment: In this context same ID is acceptable, I mean it does not break anything. What *does* break things is missing `data-name` attributes. See my reply below.

Comment: There's no `data-name="XXX"` anywhere in your HTML. What are `value.dataset.name` and `e.target.dataset.name` supposed to be?

Comment: @alx It does break it -- Clicking on the second row doesn't do anything.

Comment: There's no need to test `dataset.name` in the loop. You can use ```$(`#tbody tr td[data-name=${e.target.dataset.name}]`)``` to match them in the selector.

Comment: It would also be simpler if you put `data-name` in the `tr` rather than duplicating it in every `td`.

Comment: Indeed, it does break it. Need to change event binding if you want to use same ID everywhere: `$(document).on('click', "#test" e => ...`. But I agree that's not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine except one little thing: all your input selectors lack closing quote and bracket, e.g. this is wrong (jQuery 3.3.1 throws error):

```js
let sname = $("input[name*='name_type");
```

But this is right:

```js
let sname = $("input[name*='name_type']");
```

Otherwise, it works just fine (well, certain optimizations can be done, that's true, but still it works as is) -- if I have guessed your HTML structure correctly, see example below. (Disclaimer: this is by no means a good piece of code with best pracrices etc. This is just a reproduction of original task with minimal fix to make it work.)

```js
$(document).ready(e => {
  $(".btnedit").click(e => {
    textvalues = displayData(e);
    let sname = $("input[name*='name_type']");
    let sage = $("input[name*='age_type']");
    let sgender = $("input[name*='gender_type']");
    sname.val(textvalues[0]);
    sage.val(textvalues[1]);
    sgender.val(textvalues[2]);
  });
});

function displayData(e) {
  let i = 0;
  const td = $("#tbody tr td");
  let textvalues = [];

  for (const value of td) {
    if (value.dataset.name == e.target.dataset.name) {
      textvalues[i++] = value.textContent;
    }
  }
  return textvalues;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td data-name="1">a1</td>
      <td data-name="1">b1</td>
      <td data-name="1">c1</td>
      <td><button class="btnedit" data-name="1">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-name="2">a2</td>
      <td data-name="2">b2</td>
      <td data-name="2">c2</td>
      <td><button class="btnedit" data-name="2">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Type: <input type="text" name="name_type" /><br />
Age: <input type="text" name="age_type" /><br />
Gender: <input type="text" name="gender_type" />
```

Possible reason of could be this: `data-name` is invalid everywhere in your table. If that's not the case, please share some more code. Minimal yet complete example would be great.

Update: in your example HTML I see no `data-name` attributes at all, and clickable element also does not have it. So, your selector `$('#tbody th td')` matches *all* TDs, and that's why you see whole table in output.

So, look at the example above and do the same with `data-name`: every `<td>` and the button on one row have the same value in that attribute.

Comment: Those must be copying errors, or his code wouldn't run at all.

Comment: The quotes are correct in his github page: https://github.com/akashyap2013/PHP_CRUD_Operation/blob/master/php/main.js

Comment: Your jsfiddle link goes to an empty fiddle.

Comment: Fixed that couple of mins ago.

Comment: @alx Indeed it was me not naming the `data-name` properly. But when I applied the fix nothing gets stored in the array. And if I put the `data-name` in `tr` all elements of the array get stored as earlier.

Comment: If you want to use `data-name` with `tr`, you need to change selector accordingly. But this is just an optimization, probably not a good idea right now as you're struggling to make the code work in general. As to your PHP snippet, you should add `data-name` to element with `btnedit` class -- not to its parent. So, last `td` should look like this: `<td><i class="fas fa-edit btnedit" data-name = "<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"></i></td>`

Comment: I noticed it in the source code now, it wasn't correct in the video I was following